# Android project missing CMake license

Tags: android, gradle, cmake

I have installed the following SDK components on my CI machine via commandline:

- tools_r25.2.3-macosx
- android-ndk-r13b-darwin-x86_64
- platform-tools,tools, extra-google-m2repository,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-m2repository,extra-android-support, build-tools-25.0.1,android-25

I have also copied licenses from my developer machine into **/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/My_App_Android_Gradle/workspace/android-sdk-macosx/licenses**

However, when I try to build my NDK project, I get this error:

> Checking the license for package CMake 3.6.3155560 in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/My_App_Android_Gradle/workspace/android-sdk-macosx/licenses
>
> Warning: License for package CMake 3.6.3155560 not accepted.
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_ProductionDebugApk'.
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':jni-code'.
>     You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>         [CMake 3.6.3155560].
>         Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>
> Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

This error does not make a lot of sense to me, and the above link is outdated anyway.  Furthermore, there is no license for CMake in the /android-sdk-macos/license directory.  So where can I obtain the CMake license from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.  The issue was with the *license* files in the $sdk/licenses directory.  To resolve:

- delete the $sdk/licenses directory on CI machine
- recreate the $sdk/licenses directory on CI machine with the following files (which you should copy from your local machine):

**android-sdk-license**, **android-sdk-preview-license**

Now, CMake installs and builds fine.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and I solved it by installing CMake directly (I couldn't license transfer from Windows to UNIX build machine).

Here is the command to install using [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html#usage) :

```
sdkmanager "cmake;3.6.3155560"
```

Get the list of available packages by:

```
sdkmanager --list
```

Comment: This actually saved me. Tks. Using it here: https://github.com/lovato/docker-bob/blob/develop/android/ndk/Dockerfile